# Проверка введенных данных в поле prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я новичок и честно говоря, просто не нашел четкого ответа в гугле. Что я написал не так? Хотелось бы, что бы выполнялось условие при введении одного из значений массива, а в противном случае другое условие.

```
var name_arr = new Array("me", "you", "they");
var z;
var y = name_arr[y];
if (confirm("would you download this file?")) {
    z = prompt("who are you?", "me");
    if (z.value = name_arr[y]){
        alert("hello" + name_arr[y]);
    }
    else {
        alert("user not found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А что такое у Вас `var y = name_arr[y];`?
Если используете jquery (в тегах указан), то примерно так можно

```js
var name_arr = new Array("me", "you", "they");
var z;
if (confirm("would you download this file?")) {
    z = prompt("who are you?", "me");
    if ($.inArray(z, name_arr) != -1){ //проверяем наличие введенного значения в массиве
        alert("hello " + z);
    }
    else {
        alert("user not found");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вот оно! Я просто не знал про метод inArray, что бы работать с элементами массива. Спасибо!

Comment: Поменяйте условие на `name_arr.indexOf(z) != -1` и выкиньте нахрен jQuery, он не нужен

Comment: Только вы забыли сказать, что indexOf для массивов поддерживается в IE только начиная с 9-ого, если поддержка IE 8  и меньше не нужна, то, конечно, можно использовать. А про jquery, я вообще-то, написал, "если используете", т.к. в тегах он указан, что подразумевает, что jquery уже подключен для других задач.